# is it illegal to coast down a hill in New York State?

Tags: law, vehicle

is it illegal to put your car in neutral while going down a slope in New York state? Take into account that there are no stop signs, and red lights on this hill or during time of neutral.

Comment: Can you give us a link to where you have seen this claim made?

Comment: I can see this is getting close votes, presumably because it isn't a notable claim. The only reason I don't also vote to close, is that it got a simple, definitive answer within minutes, which addressed the "not worth bothering" and probably the "attacking a strawman" aspects of non-notable claims.

Answer (score 3):

It was as of 2012. [Article 33 section 1216 of the New York Vehicle and Traffic act](http://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2013/vat/title-7/article-33/1216) states:

> § 1216. Coasting  prohibited.  The  driver  of  any motor vehicle when
>     traveling upon a down grade shall not  coast  with  the  gears  of  such
>     vehicle in neutral, nor with the clutch disengaged.

Comment: California too, for what it's worth.  http://www.bestattorney.com/california-motor-vehicle-code/coasting-downhill-21710.html